# Outlook adds margin top to images smaller than 15px

Tags: html, css, image, outlook

I send a two simple emails with one image each (50px high and 2px high)

```
<html>
    <body>
         <img src="http://placehold.it/600x50/00ff00"/>
        <br />
        Lorem ipsum
    </body>
</html>
```

and

```
<html>
    <body>
         <img src="http://placehold.it/600x2/00ff00"/>
        <br />
        Lorem ipsum
    </body>
</html>
```

Here are the results from Outlook 2013

[image: outlook image height problem]

As you can see, the left image has a smaller margin to the top than the right image - the margin between the very top and the left image is the unavoidable 15px Outlook default margin - but I'm not talking about that.
It seem that Outlook adds another margin to the image on the right since it is smaller than the line-height which is about 15px.
I have tried everything possible: setting `display: block`, `line-height: 0`, `mso-line-height-rule: exactly`, etc. I even tried wrapping the image in a `div` or a `span` but nothing helped.

It's easy to reproduce with e.g. [putsmail.com](http://putsmail.com).
Any ideas or suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: It may be the `<br>` that causes the issue, not the `<img>`. Test if it helps to remove the `<br>` and to wrap the `<img>` in a `<div>` (or to give it display:block).

Comment: first thing wrap the `image` and `text` inside `table` with two different `tr` if still doesnt work then add `line-height`  to the `tr` same as the  `image` `height`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up wrapping the image in a `<div />`. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word as an email editor. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following series of articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Hope you will find this information helpful.